# python itertools groupby return empty

Tags: python, python-itertools

I'm very confusing why result of itertools.groupby has converted into list, still return empty? But you can see the correct print result!

```
from itertools import groupby

sample = [['data', '8', '1', '14:05:00', '15:05:00', 'fall'], ['data', '8', '1', '14:45:00', '15:45:00', 'winter']]

arr= []

for i2,i in groupby(data, key=lambda x: x[5]):
    print(i2, list(i))
    arr.append(list(i))

print(arr)
```

Why arr is empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because Python iterator can only be iterated **once**.

For example:

```
def f():
    for i in range(5):
        yield i

i = f() # i is an iterator

list(i) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
# i has been iterated once, now it's empty
list(i) # []
```

In your case `i` is an iterator, and it's been iterated in `print`, so removing the `print` or assign it to a variable before printing:

```
l = list(i)
print(i2, l)
arr.append(l)
```

should give you the expected result.